# Choosing a right paradigm to implement a specific programing task

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I have a following architecture:

[image]

Main Control Unit(MCU) here must: run TCP/IP server for communication with robot; run Redis Database; be able to run several data processing programs (where data sent by robot or obtained from Redis is used). External Control Unit is connected to Redis DB.

I have to write program for MCU. Ideally it must be able to perform asynchronously following tasks:

- Get request from robot and pass it to Redis DB, so External Control Unit can react to the signal appearance and start acquiring data from sensor (Then publishing this data to Redis DB).
- Get request from robot to start receiving data from robot (Then publish this data to Redis DB).
- React to the appearance of data from External Control Unit in Redis DB.  This must force Main Control Unit to start data processing program using obtained sensor data.
- Get request from robot to send resultant data to robot.

This is a simplified version of the system, since there will be more External Control Units with different sensors. But most of MCU tasks are described.
For now I can ensure data transmission between MCU and robot. And I'm pretty familiar with publishing/subscribing techniques of Redis DB.

But I'm struggling with choosing proper technology/paradigm to program MCU, asynchronous/multithreading/multiprocessing programming? Where to dig?

**Addition to question:**

Which paradigm (asynchronous/multithreading/multiprocessing programming) is better to use to implement such a behavior of MCU:

- MCU receive request from robot to start up computer vision routine (it takes around 30-40 seconds to be finished). The routine can be started only if necessary data are found in redis DB. So, may be MCU must wait until ExtXU end publishing this data into DB, may be not. After the routine has been started, during 30-40 seconds of CV routine run, another request from robot can come, and it must be processed while CV routine is running.

I studied today an asyncio python module, and in my mind it's not suitable to implement what I want. It is ideal for processing multiple client requests on server, or trying to get some data from different servers from one client. A coroutines lock/wait  is essential, so program can do something else while coroutine waits something. But my CV routine do not wait anything, it just runs.

Comment: Doing async work in python is *very* painful, compared against other languages like javascript. My recommendation would be to write the MCU in nodejs (whose event-driven model is specifically designed to solve this kind of problem), then write everything else in python.

Comment: @JonathanDBVanSchenck thanks for answering. To write MCU program in nodejs, firstly I must learn nodejs itself. What is simpler in your opinion, learn nodejs or async work in python? Moreover, MCU data processing program (Computer Vision task) is already written in python. Thanks.

Comment: Hrmm, I see the conundrum. For myself, I would make the decision based on a few considerations: 1) how familiar with python are you? if you are pretty comfortable, than learning how to force python to be event-driven might not be too bad; however if you are still a beginner with python, it really might be better to just pick another language which works out-of-the-box.

Comment: 2) python is WAY better for computer vision than js, so even if you use node for the MCU, you may still want to call your python process from the node thread.

Comment: If you do end up using nodejs for the MCU, here is a library that my company wrote which makes handling TCP connections for passing data a bit easier to work with: https://github.com/Daxbot/sockhop, also if you want to have various systems be reactive to data, this library (https://github.com/Daxbot/entangld) implements a pub/sub datastore model which works nicely over sockets. We have python clients for both to these too -- let me know and I can send then to you.

Comment: @JonathanDBVanSchenck thanks again.  I think I'll try to sort out the python async way. 
If I fail I'll try node js. 
Actually, I was asking about different thing, I have revised my question and understood that I missed some essential info to clarify my question. I have added some explanation to question to clarify things up.

Comment: I think you definitely want to go the mutlithreading approach for the CV task. Async in python is technically still single threaded, so if you start a 30 second CV task as an async function, everything else (like other request handlers) will be blocked while the task runs (unless you specifically put a `asyncio.sleep(...)` in your task, which it sounds like you don't want to). The ideal with multithreading is that you are creating a separate process for the CV task which will allow your MCU to keep doing other things while CV task completes.